# How to have a common legend for subplots?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend, figure, subplot

I am trying to create a figure of subplots. I don't want the subplots to have legends but instead the figure to have an overall legend.

I read that it is possible either by adding a legend only to the last subplot and adjusting its location in the figure through the `position` feature of `legend` or by using one subplot figure position (e.g. `subplot(2,3,5.5)` only for displaying the legend). I would prefer the second option although I haven't succeeded up until now. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
SLS=figure();
hold on
subplot(3,2,1);
plot(t,u{1},t,u{2},t,u{3},t,u{4},t,u{5},t,u{6});
title('SLS Levels');
subplot(3,2,2);
plot(t,log_u{1},t,log_u{2},t,log_u{3},t,log_u{4},t,log_u{5},t,log_u{6});
title('SLS Logarithms');
subplot(3,2,3);
plot(t,I_u{1},t,I_u{2},t,I_u{3},t,I_u{4},t,I_u{5},t,I_u{6});
title('SLS Levels with Intercept');
subplot(3,2,4);
plot(t,log_I_u{1},t,log_I_u{2},t,log_I_u{3},t,log_I_u{4},t,log_I_u{5},t,log_I_u{6});
title('SLS Log. with Intercept');
subplot(3,2,5.5);
legend('GDP', 'C', 'I', 'G', 'Imp.', 'Exp.');
axis off
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Code:**

```
% Plotting some random data and storing their handles
subplot(3,2,1);       h1 = plot(randperm(10),randperm(10),'ko-');
subplot(3,2,2);       h2 = plot(randperm(10),randperm(10),'g+-');
subplot(3,2,3);       h3 = plot(randperm(10),randperm(10),'md-');
subplot(3,2,4);       h4 = plot(randperm(10),randperm(10),'rv-.');

hL = subplot(3,2,5.5);
poshL = get(hL,'position');     % Getting its position

lgd = legend(hL,[h1;h2;h3;h4],'RandomPlot1','RandomPlot2','RandomPlot3','RandomPlot4');
set(lgd,'position',poshL);      % Adjusting legend's position
axis(hL,'off');                 % Turning its axis off
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: My take-away from this is that you can have `0.5` increments in subplots, didn't know that! Neat solution.

Comment: I'd add that the first argument of `subplot()` must be an integer, but the others evidently don't have to be!